# Tensorboard processing for DLC File

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm looking at a DLC file which represents the graph used for a neural network inside of the Snapdragon Neural Processing Engine.

https://developer.qualcomm.com/docs/snpe/model_conv_tensorflow.html

I would like to visualize this model in something like tensorboard. My understanding is tensorboard requires PB file which is used by tensorflow to save graphs.

Is there any way to convert a DLC file to a Tensorflow PB for visualization or another way to achieve this aim?

Answer (score 0):

NPE SDK does not provide tool to convert a DLC file to PB/Any other framework supported model.

A platform like Tensorboard, which helps in debug and visualization of the model created are not available from NPE SDK.